# Determine static library cpu architecture on *nix

Tags: unix, static-libraries, cpu-architecture

There is a static library but i am not sure compiled for sparc or x86 architecture. How to determine this on linux/unix ?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found objdump tool,

objdump -f FILE_NAME

Comment: So when it writes `architecture: i386:x86-64` it's 64 bit architecture, right?

Comment: Yes, It refers to 64bit architecture